# Atom.io find in project not working

Tags: atom-editor

I am trying to use the "find in project" feature of Atom editor.

I am coming from sublime and assumed that opening a folder is the equivalent of opening a project. Is this assumption correct?

If so, then I have a project open. I then search from a string using "Find in project". I am certain the string exists, and the file type is not ignored, yet it still returns no result.

Comment: Is your file encoded in utf-8 ? There is a bug if your file is not encoded in utf-8 and if you are looking for a string with non-ansi character, such as "café"

Comment: Also watch out for the "exclude VCS ignored paths" option in the core settings.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue, and it only affected one project - a project in a git repo.
I checked the settings of the search field.. they were fine.

My issue was, as @fab313 mentioned above, as the setting in Core > Exclude VCS ignored paths.

Once I unchecked that box (Atom menu, Preferences, Core).. all project searches worked fine!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I found that I accidentally clicked some of the settings boxes in the bottom right.

**You just want to make sure you know which boxes are checked**.

[image]

If I check one of those boxes (making them blue) then my CTRL/Command + F will only find a single result.

The settings will look like this and cause the problems for me:
[image]